# Dynamic keys from values in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Say I have this:

```
{
        "_id" : "ENVD",
        "years" : [
                {
                        "year" : "2013",
                        "avgInstructor" : 5.144999999999998
                },
                {
                        "year" : "2012",
                        "avgInstructor" : 5.194436090225564
                }
        ]
}
```

I need to be able to find the difference in the avgInstructor field from 2012-13. I was thinking I could transform the keys somehow using a `$project` which would make the year be the key, and the avgInstructor rating be the value. So it would look like this:

```
{
        "_id" : "ENVD",
        "years" : {
                        "2013" : 5.144999999999998,
                        "2012" : 5.194436090225564
         }

}
```

Is this possible? Keep in mind my main goal is to be able to run a subtraction like this pseudocode : `years['2013'].avgInstructor - years['2013'].avgInstructor`. So if you see an easier way, that would be great as well. I am not sure of the best way to go about this in the context of an aggregation pipeline. Can someone help?

Comment: Never ceases to amaze me why anyone would think this is a good thing in preference to how it is already stored. Also no matter what you want to do here, it is likely going to be more efficient in code if you are not actually aggregating anything between documents.

Comment: Did you see my comment about offering a better solution if you see one? You comment doesn't help very much. A few notes: 1) This is a small dataset, so performance is not of utmost priority. 2) I was asked to complete this using *only* a Mongo query. It is mostly a learning experience, and I would much prefer to actually code this out (it is a relatively simple problem, then).

Comment: Well I think it does and at least one person agrees. It seems the best solution is to leave it as it is. What is wrong with just subtracting :`years[0].avgInstructor - years[1].avgInstructor` or with `indexOf("2013)` after a `map()` for the field value to get the element index or whatever language equiv notations. You are not aggregating documents, so it seems like unnecessary work.

Answer (score 5):

For people that ends up here looking for a solution to transform an array to an object using aggregation in a more recent version of MongoDB:

MongoDB 3.4.4 introduced [$arrayToObject](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/)

You have to [$map](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) `years`

```
  {
    $set: {
      years: {
        $map: {
          input: "$years",
          as: "year",
          in: [
            "$$year.year",
            "$$year.avgInstructor"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

to be like this

```js
{
  "_id" : "ENVD",
  "years": [
    ["2013", 5.144999999999998],
    ["2012", 5.194436090225564]
  ]
}
```

then use [$arrayToObject](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/)

```
  {
    $set: {
      years: {
        $arrayToObject: "$years"
      }
    }
  }
```

Or combine the two steps together

```
  {
    $set: {
      years: {
        $arrayToObject: {
          $map: {
            input: "$years",
            as: "year",
            in: [
              "$$year.year",
              "$$year.avgInstructor"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

A Possible answer ...

1. Unwind first
2. project to make it a little easier to handle
3. Sort on _id and then on year
4. group by _id to pickup the first and the last value
5. final projection to get subtracted value

   ```
   db.coll.aggregate ( [

           { "$unwind" : "$years"  } ,

           { $project : { "year" : "$years.year", "avgInstructor" : "$years.avgInstructor"  } },

           { $sort : { "_id" : 1, "year" : 1 } },

           { $group : { "_id" : "$_id", "val_min" : { $first : "$avgInstructor"  },  "val_max" : { $last : "$avgInstructor" } } },

           { $project : { "diff" : { $subtract : [ "$val_min", "$val_max" ] }  } }

   ] )
   ```